# can start and stop BLE scan for every one second once?

Tags: android, android-ble

In my app, I have to stop and start the `BLE scan` for every seconds. In this case scan result are not updating properly and also getting scan failed error like

> a BLE scan with the same settings is already started by the app

Is this every seconds restart the scan correct?

Comment: can you explain why are you doing a start scan and stop scan every second?

Comment: In my app need to update the device in list adapter when the device got detected. So in this case i am restating scanning for every seconds.

Comment: try to update the only list. whenever new device found or just refresh list every 10 sec.